# Fitting a polynomial

Tags: r, polynomials

I want to calculate the fitted value for a polynomial.

I would like to calculate 'fit' but without adjusting for the variable 'z'.

What I have now is cumbersome, and eventually I would like to iterate through different power polynomials without having to add one more term to the above equation for 'fit' every time.

```
x <- runif(n = 50, min = 1, max = 10)
y <- runif(n = 50, min = 10, max = 20)
z <- sample(letters[1:5], 50, TRUE)

f <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 5, raw=TRUE) + as.factor(z), na.action=na.exclude)

fit <- f$coeff[1] + f$coeff[2]*x + f$coeff[3]*x^2 + f$coeff[4]*x^3 + 
  f$coeff[5]*x^4 + 
  f$coeff[6]*x^5
```

Comment: Defined like that, `z` is a continuous variable (`runif`) coerced to factor. The result is as many levels as vector elements. Try, say with 4 levels, `z<- sample(4, 50, TRUE)`. Or, with 5 levels,  `z<- sample(letters[1:5], 50, TRUE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the parametrization R uses for fitting a factor is to add a dummy variable for all levels except the first.  So if you want the prediction for your data to exclude the coefficients for the factor `z`, just ask for predictions where `x` takes on the true values, and `z` takes on its first level (probably `"a"` in your case, but sampling might never give an `"a"`, so it's better to use `levels(as.factor(z))[1]`.

That is:

```
newdata <- data.frame(x = x, z = levels(as.factor(z))[1])
fit <- predict(f, newdata = newdata)
```

I'd be slightly worried that something might go wrong in computing `as.factor()` in `newdata` (though it appears to give the same values as your formula), so I'd recommend a slightly different overall approach:  change `z` to a factor before
calling `lm()`.  That is,

```
z <- as.factor(z)
f <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 5, raw=TRUE) + z, na.action=na.exclude)
levs <- levels(z)
newdata <- data.frame(x = x, z = factor(levs[1], levels = levs))
fit <- predict(f, newdata = newdata)
```